# Points plot (marker) in pcolor/surfplot Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a nice plot using pcolor, but I would like to place some points/dots/marker on specific area in my plot. I have a domain of 600 (y-direction) and 1200 (x-direction), and I would like to have the dot, for example, at x = 600 and y=300.

I did the following:

```
figure; pcolor(X,Y,Z_interpolate); shading flat; 
hold on
x = [ 600; 700 ...]; 
y = [ 300; 300 ...];
plot(x,y,'.','r');
```

However, plotting the dots in the figure do not show up (pcolor plot for my figure works fine). I think it has something to do with the 'plot'- function I used in combination with pcolor, but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That does not clarify. Was there an error? Did the points not show up?

Comment: The points did not show up. Matlab gave only the following error: ''Error using plot''

Comment: Try this `plot(x,y,'.r')`

Comment: Try `'.r'` instead of `'.', 'r'`

Answer (score 0):

In continue to the comments, here is a quick example with demo data:

```
n = 10;
r = (0:n)'/n;
theta = pi*(-n:n)/n;
X = r*cos(theta);
Y = r*sin(theta);
Z_interpolate = r*cos(2*theta);
pcolor(X,Y,Z_interpolate); shading flat; 
hold on
x = [0 0.5 -0.5 0 0]; 
y = [0 0 0 0.5 -0.5];
plot(x,y,'or');
```

Which create this:
[image: pcolor example]

You can replace the `o` in the `plot` function with all other types of markers, like `.`